# sharepoint explorer view

Tags: sharepoint

can someone please tell me what i need so that i can see the explorer view for a library in sharepoint? it works on one machine and not another. it sometimes works on a vista client but not xp. it works in internet explorer but does not work on another machine with  the same settings.

please help. wss 3.0 on windows server 2008 with vista and xp clients.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It requires WebDav to be enabled on the server part, and WebClient to be running at the client. WebClient is just a service, see [this technet entry](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/844f5e01-4b9e-4dac-897e-2a0bb33f28af.mspx?mfr=true) for specific information on how to start it.

If WebClient is already running, make sure the SharePoint site is added to the "Trusted Sites" in IE. In Vista SP1 and up, the WebClient has a private list of "Trusted Sites" [in the registry](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-do-i-make-our-sharepoint-site-stop.html).

Comment: I think you also have to have some version of Office installed, probably either 2003 or 2007.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint explorer view actually doesn't work in IE8 on Windows XP SP3.  The issue only occurs if your using SSL, and I've not seen a good solution to make this work.  Interestingly, it works fine in IE7.  Now if your using any other web browser besides IE, there is no way to get explorer view to work currently.

Also, the 64bit version of IE is a Level 2 browser with SharePoint 2007, so certain features don't work on that either.  I think the explorer view is one of them, but my memory could be wrong.  Microsoft has [published](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx) what currently does and does not work between different browsers on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a site collection located at your web application root. This solved the problem in my case.

Problem : explorer view not working properly, except when :

- explorer view selected in a subfolder of the document library
- a network favorite pointing to the document library was created

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do a quick backup of a bunch of files, and the explorer view was not working.  What finally worked was mapping a network drive to the sharepoint server, and then I was able to bulk copy and paste the folders/files to my backup server.

I don't know why MS makes so many things really difficult.  But they do.  But that worked for me.